# Google Drive API service account - file sharing within domain

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-python-client

I am trying to manage file sharing permission within certain domain using a service account.

Here is the process:

1. Authorize thru a service account
2. Create a folder using service account
3. Upload all the files under the folder
4. Insert the permission on the folder with

```
user_permission = {
    'value': issuer_email, (ex. user@company.com)
    'type': 'user',
    'role': 'writer'
}
drive_service.permissions().insert(fileId=f_id, body=user_permission, fields="id").execute()
domain_permission = {
     'type': 'domain',
     'role': 'writer',
     'domain': 'company.com'
}
drive_service.permissions().insert(fileId=f_id, body=domain_permission, fields="id").execute()
```

For the first 3 steps it goes well. But I am not getting the error for the step (4):

> <HttpError 400 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/1RqQUiSKP05ELbPX18YpcoqTGTG_RD2j4/permissions?fields=id&alt=json returned "Permission value field required">

I tried resolving this error by adding different fields but no luck. Also its generating the file and folder I wanted, but the folders and files can be share outside the company domain. (with the `share` button enable there and I can access it from other domain.)

So how can I limit the file sharing within the domain? Like in the Google Drive UI prompt for sharing, if I choose any email address which is not qualified, it should not be able to share.

Thanks!!! If I am not even on the right track, please kindly give me some pointer for how to do this.

**UPDATES**

To be more specific, I would want to achieve this:

[image: Permission Sharing]

With the second input field, though I can share files with ppl outside the domain, but ppl would need to ask for permission to access it. 
For not its not asking for permission.

Comment: Any reason why you are using Google drive v2 instead of Google Drive v3?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have some extra code with your value that is probably causing your issue.  Try checking the documented example

```
file_id = '1sTWaJ_j7PkjzaBWtNc3IzovK5hQf21FbOw9yLeeLPNQ'
def callback(request_id, response, exception):
    if exception:
        # Handle error
        print exception
    else:
        print "Permission Id: %s" % response.get('id')

batch = drive_service.new_batch_http_request(callback=callback)
user_permission = {
    'type': 'user',
    'role': 'writer',
    'value': 'user@example.com'
}
batch.add(drive_service.permissions().insert(
        fileId=file_id,
        body=user_permission,
        fields='id',
))
domain_permission = {
    'type': 'domain',
    'role': 'reader',
    'value': 'example.com'
}
batch.add(drive_service.permissions().insert(
        fileId=file_id,
        body=domain_permission,
        fields='id',
))
batch.execute()
```

Code ripped from the documentation for Drive v2 [manage sharing](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/manage-sharing)

Comment: Thanks @DalmTo!!! I tried the code above, it runs without errors but its not granting the correct permission -- I can still share the files with ppl not in the domain, and they don't need asking the owner for access the document -- which is not I wanted. Am I missing anything? I am editing my question above with the pic for the parts I wanted. Thanks!

Comment: You cant grant access to a file you dont own.  The service account needs to own the file before its going to be able to grant others permissions to the file.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a service account to upload and share files, you should make sure that "**sendNotificationEmails**" is set to **False** to avoid "You cannot share this item because it has been flagged as inappropriate." The reason is that the api is trying to avid spamming with emails users that potentially has nothing to do with your shared-file.